# How to optimize a nested foreach loop which is creating same data object (with different values)

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have following code which gets MastrSegments from repository(entity framework). It's working but I think I am  violating [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) (though not sure).

MastrSegments conatins collection of SegReqs and SegReq contains collection Routes. And I am looping through them to update `RootObject`

```
    foreach (var MastrSegment in MastrSegments)
    {

        var segReqCount = MastrSegment.segReqs.Count();

        var MastrSegmentRow = new Row
        {
            c = new RootObject[] { new RootObject { v = MastrSegment.Name }, new RootObject { v = "TopClient" }, new RootObject { v = segReqCount }, new RootObject { v = 12 } }

        };

        foreach (var segReq in MastrSegment.segReqs)
        {

            var routesCount = segReq.routess.Count;
            Row segReqRow;

            if (segReq.Name != MastrSegment.Name)
            {
                segReqRow = new Row
                {
                    c = new RootObject[] { new RootObject { v = segReq.Name }, new RootObject { v = MastrSegment.Name }, new RootObject { v = routesCount }, new RootObject { v = -26 } }

                };
            }
            else
            {
                throw new NotSupportedException("MastrSegment name and  segReq name can not be same !!");
            }


            foreach (var routes in segReq.routess)
            {
                var circuitsCount = routes.Circuits.Count;
                Row routesRow = null;

                if (routes.Name != segReq.Name)
                {
                     routesRow = new Row
                    {
                        c = new RootObject[] { new RootObject { v = routes.Name }, new RootObject { v = segReq.Name }, new RootObject { v = circuitsCount }, new RootObject { v = 16 } }

                    };
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new NotSupportedException("segReq name and  routes name can not be same !!");
                }

                rows.Add(routesRow);
            }

            rows.Add(segReqRow);
        }


        rows.Add(MastrSegmentRow);
    }

    var returnData = rows.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 3):

when ever you want to solve violations of the *DRY* principle you have to convert *similar code* into *equal code*.

If you look at the two inner loops: make the most inner loop using new *local variables* to replace the differeing parts

> ```
>        {
>             var circuitsCount = routes.Circuits.Count;
>             Row routesRow = null;
>
>             if (routes.Name != segReq.Name)
>             {
>                  routesRow = new Row
>                 {
>                     c = new RootObject[] { new RootObject { v = routes.Name }, new RootObject { v = segReq.Name }, new RootObject { v = circuitsCount }, new RootObject { v = 16 } }
>
>                 };
>             }
>             else
>             {
>                 throw new NotSupportedException("segReq name and  routes name can not be same !!");
>             }
>
>             rows.Add(routesRow);
>         }
> ```

becomes

```
       { // may be no valid syntax since I'm not a C# guy...
            var count = routes.Circuits.Count;
            Row routesRow = null;
            var master = "routes"
            var masterName = routes.Name;
            var detail = "segReq"
            var detailName = segReq.Name;
            var magicNumber =  16;

            if (masterName != detailName )
            {
                 routesRow = new Row
                {
                    c = new RootObject[] { new RootObject { v = masterName }, new RootObject { v = detailName }, new RootObject { v = count }, new RootObject { v =  magicNumber } }

                };
            }
            else
            {
                throw new NotSupportedException(detail+" name and "+master+" name can not be same !!");
            }

            rows.Add(routesRow);
        }
```

now you extract the "future common" part to a new method:

```
       {
            var count = routes.Circuits.Count;
            var master = "routes"
            var masterName = routes.Name;
            var detail = "segReq"
            var detailName = segReq.Name;
            var = magicNumber  16;

            Row routesRow = CreateMasterDetailRow(master, masterName, detail, detailName, count, magicNumber);
            rows.Add(routesRow);
        }
//...

func Row CreateMasterDetailRow(var master, var masterName, var detail, var detailName, var count, var magicNumber)
{

            if (masterName != detailName )
            {
                 return new Row
                {
                    c = new RootObject[] { new RootObject { v = masterName }, new RootObject { v = detailName }, new RootObject { v = circuitsCount }, new RootObject { v =  magicNumber } }

                };
            }
            else
            {
                throw new NotSupportedException(detail+" name and "+master+" name can not be same !!");
            } 
}
```

*inline* the extracted variables into the function call:

```
       {
            Row routesRow = CreateMasterDetailRow("routes", routes.Name, "segReq", segReq.Name, routes.Circuits.Count, 16);
            rows.Add(routesRow);
        }
```

then use the call in the middle loop:

```
   {  // maybe I got the order of "master" and "detail" wrong...
        Row segReqRow= CreateMasterDetailRow("MastrSegment ", MastrSegment.Name, "segReq", segReq.Name, segReq.routess.Count, -26);
        foreach (var routes in segReq.routess)
        {
            Row routesRow = CreateMasterDetailRow("routes", routes.Name, "segReq", segReq.Name, routes.Circuits.Count, 16);
            rows.Add(routesRow);
        }
        rows.Add(segReqRow);
```

You can even replace the similar code in the outer loop if you provide some "fake data" for the (not failing) consistency check to satify the new methods parameter list...